# Finding a specific solution to $X^T\Sigma X = D$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, convex-optimization

I'm looking to solve for a specific $X$ in the following equation:
$$X^T\Sigma X = D,$$
where $\Sigma \succ 0$, $D$ is a diagonal matrix with strictly positive entries, and all matrices are square. It may also be worth noting that $\det(\Sigma) = \det(D)$.

I'm looking for a (known to exist) solution $X$ which can be written as $I-W$, where $W$ is permutation-similar to a strictly-triangular matrix. Using Sylvester's Law of Inertia, I'm able to solve for an $X$ by finding the transformation which converts $\Sigma$ and $D$ to the same diagonal matrix (since they both have all positive entries). However, I don't know how to take this solution to one that matches the form I-W as described above.

Alternatively, I've also considered how one might solve this with the solution to a convex program, but haven't had much success so far.

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ real? Then $X$ is an orthogonal matrix that diagonalizes $\Sigma$. Then you have still some freedom to play with $X$.

Comment: Yes, $\Sigma$ is real. Thanks, I've found how to solve for an arbitrary $X$. I'm trying specifically to recover a solution $X$ that is of the form $I-W$ (doesn't have to be orthogonal, and in fact I'd expect it not to be).

Comment: @Allen94, You should share your solution for the arbitrary case. It might give people ideas to solve your specific case.